# Net:Http only want part of the response

Tags: ruby, siri

So I am using this:

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
```

Works perfect.

Issue I am having is that the page it gets is formatted with head, html, body, etc tags.
There is a label element in the body with an id of "Result" I only want to get me back the text of "Result". Not all the html formatting.

Can this be done?

Comment: could you show the all relevant codes to see what you are now getting? and what you actually want to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to get only a part of a content in HTML you have to use a HTML parser, which will be [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) in this case .

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css('#Result').each do |re|
  puts re.to_s
  #puts re.content
end
```

Comment: That does work. But I actually decided to blank out the aspx page with a asp: literal. Then there is no formatting on the page.

Comment: you could also return JSON, much easier to parse .